# MySQL Update Ignore not working - errors and does not update all rows

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, update

I am trying to run an update on a table which I know will cause some duplicate key errors. I am therefore using `UPDATE IGNORE` as I understood this would ignore these errors and still update the rest of the table, but this is not the case - it just fails with an error:

```
[SQL] UPDATE IGNORE `activity-customer` set `customerid` = 12345 where `customerid` = 56789 

[Err] 1062 - Duplicate entry '12345-180221' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

SQL_MODE is not set to STRICT (it is empty)

This is using MySQL 5.5.47.

I'm very confused! Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you please provide the exact table structure and the result of `SELECT * FROM activity-customer WHERE customerid = 56789`?

Comment: Do you get errors or warnings?

Comment: I get an error - as above- [Err] 1062 - Duplicate entry

I will post table structure tomorrow

Comment: Yes, it would be good to check - what structure, may be some other settings, because I can not reproduce error not on one from several versions and even with sql_mode strict, always work as expected when used IGNORE keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to track this one down. There was a trigger on the table which was updating / inserting into another table.

The update/insert on this trigger did NOT have an ignore and it was actually that which was throwing the key error, not the original update.

Adding the ignore into that trigger code resolved the problem.